# Poisson and Geometric Distribution Independence Computation

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose we have $A \sim Poisson (\lambda)$ and $B \sim Geometric(p)$, where $A$ and $B$ are independent. 
Calculate $P(A=a \mid A <B)$

My attempt: 
\begin{align*}
P(A=a \mid A<B)&=\frac{P((A=a) \cap (A<B))}{P(A<B)}\\
&=\frac{P(A=a) \cdot P(a<B)}{P(A<B)} \mbox{ (by independence})\\
&=\frac{\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{a}}{a!} \cdot (1-p)^{a}}{P(A<B)}
\end{align*}

So how I know how to calculate the denominator $P(A<B)$.
However, I'm unsure if my numerator is correct, it just a somewhat lengthy calculation I do not show here. $\textbf{Should the numerator be just $P(a<B)$ or is mine correct with $P(A=a) \cdot P(a<B)$?}$

For example, if I was asked to calculate $P(A<B \mid B=b)$, $\textbf{would the numerator of this probability be $P(A<b)$ or would it be $P(A<b) \cdot P(B=b)$?}$
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The point is that in the first one the event $A=a \cap A<B$ is not just $a<B$. It is however $A=a \cap a<B$, which doesn't result in any nice cancellation with the denominator in the conditional probability.

In the second one you again have $A<B \cap B=b=A<b \cap B=b$, but now you do get some cancellation because $P(B=b)$ in the numerator will cancel with $P(B=b)$ in the denominator. The difference was that the condition only involved one of the variables in the second case.

Comment: @tiger123 That's right.

Comment: @tiger123 Yes, that's right. Note that it's important that the condition was $B=b$ so that $A<B \cap B=b$ could be rewritten as $A<b \cap B=b$ (an intersection of an event only involving $A$ and an event only involving $B$). If the condition had been, say, $B<b$ that would not be sufficient.

Comment: @tiger123 No, $A<B \cap B=b$ is not equal to $A<b$. Essentially "the constraint on $A$ reduces to $A<b$" but the constraint on $B$ persists. But the effect of that on the probability cancels out due to the independence.